# Getting area of part of MultiPolygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, area, multipart, multi-polygon

Is it possible, with QGIS, to get the area of a single part of a multi polygon? Or do I have to split them into single polygons?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "get"? Visualize the areas as in the image or obtaining the areas to use, for example in a script, later?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Field Calc and Expressions:

expression used:

```
array_foreach(
      generate_series(1, num_geometries($geometry)),
          round(area(geometry_n( $geometry,@element)),0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Using a script, you can get easily the areas.

- You need to check if it is multipart.
- `parts` method of `QgsGeometry` returns an iterator for parts

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = feat.geometry()
    if geom.isMultipart():
        areas = sorted([part.area() for part in geom.parts()])
        print(feat.id(), areas)
```

[image]