# Getting "QgsPolygon: CurvePolygon EMPTY" when extracting the largest part of MultiPolygon using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, area, splitting, multipart, multi-polygon

There is a shapefile with MultiPolygons, see the image below

[image: input]

With this code, I am trying to get the largest part (by area) of each MultiPolygon feature. It utilizes the [`constGet()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Geometry/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.constGet) method.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

def get_largest_part(feat):
    parts = [part for part in feat.geometry().constGet()]
    largest_part = max(parts, key=lambda x: x.area())
    return largest_part

largest_parts = [get_largest_part(feat) for feat in layer.getFeatures()]

print(largest_parts)
```

However, the output looks a bit weird. Can somebody explain to me why?

```py
[<QgsPolygon: CurvePolygon EMPTY>, <QgsPolygon: CurvePolygon EMPTY>]
```

Sometimes when running these both codes my QGIS 3.18.2-Zürich on Windows 8.1 even crashes. The same story happened when using `parts()` and `constGet()` on Ubuntu 21.10.

I tried to apply [the solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/423828/99589) suggested by @KadirŞahbaz in this thread: [Getting area of part of MultiPolygon in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423824/getting-area-of-part-of-multipolygon-in-qgis), that utilizes the [`parts()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.14/core/QgsAbstractGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsAbstractGeometry.parts) method

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

def get_largest_part(feat):
    parts = [part for part in feat.geometry().parts()]
    largest_part = sorted(parts, key=lambda x: x.area())[0]
    return largest_part
    
largest_parts = [get_largest_part(feat) for feat in layer.getFeatures()]
    
print(largest_parts)
```

however, the output is the same:

```py
[<QgsPolygon: CurvePolygon EMPTY>, <QgsPolygon: CurvePolygon EMPTY>]
```

Comment: I can't understand what's going on. In Ubuntu 21.10, QGIS always crashes when using `parts` and `constGet`.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I will include your comment in my question.

Comment: Crashing occurs usually printing largest_parts in the last line.  (rarely in the method's body) QGIS 3.24.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had success by returning a copy of the `largest_part` geometry within the function.

Unfortunately, I can't really explain why that helps, but I can only assume there is some kind of issue with variable scope.

I guess the [`QgsAbstractGeometry`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.14/core/QgsAbstractGeometry.html#) object gets *'cleared'* (to release the resources?) after it leaves the scope of the function, therefore it is an empty polygon if you access it outside of that function. Returning a deep copy with [`clone()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.14/core/QgsAbstractGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsAbstractGeometry.clone) somehow prevents this.

But that's pretty much speculation from my side.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

def get_largest_part(feat):
    parts = [part for part in feat.geometry().constGet()]
    largest_part = max(parts, key=lambda x: x.area())
    return largest_part.clone()

largest_parts = [get_largest_part(feat) for feat in layer.getFeatures()]

print(largest_parts)

# just to highlight geoms on map canvas
geoms = [QgsGeometry(p) for p in largest_parts]
iface.mapCanvas().flashGeometries(geoms, layer.crs())
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why you get empty polygons, but you can use the following script:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

def get_largest_part(feat):
    geoms = feat.geometry().asGeometryCollection()
    geom = sorted(geoms, key=lambda g: g.area(), reverse=True)[0]
    return QgsGeometry(geom)

largest_parts = [get_largest_part(feat) for feat in layer.getFeatures()]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a good idea. I have a question: have you also tried my code? Did it work?

Comment: It didn't work. I get the same result, too.

Comment: Can you please tell me, does my code look okay in terms of Python? Is it logical?