# Deleting parts of MultiPolygon based on area using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geometry, area, delete, multi-polygon

I have a layer with MultiPolygons. Some of them have parts less than five m<sup>2</sup> which I want to delete.

The `QgsGeometry` class has methods: `parts()` and `deletePart(self, partNum: int)`. On `parts()` I can apply `area()` to get the area. https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsGeometry.html

What I am missing, is a method to get the `partNum`.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is the code I came up so far. But I doubt that the index of the list `asGeometryCollection` is the same as the `numPart` index. Alternatively, I could create a new geometry, and loop over the parts, and if a part is > 5, add the part to the new geometry.

```py
# Minimum area threshold
minimum_area = 5

# Loop through all the features in the layer
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    # Retrieve the multipolygon geometry
    geometry = feature.geometry()
    geom = geometry.asGeometryCollection()
    numParts = len(geom)
    # loop over parts and numParts ( same index ??)
    for part, numPart in zip(geometry.parts(), range(numParts)):
        if part.area() < minimum_area:
            geometry.deletePart(numPart)
```

Comment: One of my previous threads can be certainly useful : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426523/getting-qgspolygon-curvepolygon-empty-when-extracting-the-largest-part-of-mul

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make a new part list from the MultiPolygon instead of deleting the parts.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Minimum area threshold
minimum_area = 2000

layer.startEditing()

# Loop through all the features in the layer
for feature in layer.getFeatures():

    # get polygons collection from geometry
    geoms = feature.geometry().asGeometryCollection()

    # filter the parts      
    filtered_geoms= [g.asPolygon() for g in geoms if g.area() > minimum_area]

    # build a new multipolygon
    new_geom = QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolygonXY(filtered_geoms)
    
    # change the geometry
    layer.changeGeometry(feature.id(), new_geom)

# layer.commitChanges()
```

Test the script. If it meets your need, uncomment the last line. It saves the changes to the data source.

[image]